# How to inject data to a Form after clicking Submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a form by clicking the `Submit` button. The form originally only consists of a `CSRF` token. When the user clicks submit, I want to fill up the form using vanilla JS with data gathered on the page.

Now here's the HTML with the form and an input field which shall be injected afterwards:

```html
<input id="user-input" type="text" name="userInput">

<form id="best-form-ever" method="post" action="/amaze-me">

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="xyz1234">
    <button id="submit-form" name="submit-form">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I have the following JavaScript code so far in place:

```js
document.querySelector("#best-form-ever").addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit, false);

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = document.getElementById("best-form-ever");
    const userInput = document.querySelector("#user-input").innerHTML;

    const payload = new FormData(form);
    payload.append("userInput", userInput);

    payload.submit(); /* this doesn't work :( */
}
```

Unfortunately, the form won't get send this way since `FormData:submit` is not a function.

So here's my question:
How can I inject additional data to a form after the submit event?

Comment: Is there a reason why the input element `userInput` is not part of the form?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. Otherwise it would be simple ;) Spring Boot provides a simple way to populate forms with `CSRF` and that's all I have at the beginning. Depending on some user actions I then will populate the form with more or less data gathered from the page and also computed on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the attribute [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form) on the input element and set the value to the ID of the form, it will be included in the form.

```html
<input type="text" name="userinput" form="bestformever">

<form id="bestformever" method="post" action="/amaze-me">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="xyz1234">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Elements can also be added on the submit event either by setting the `form` attribute on input elements or by adding elements directly to the form that is submitted:

```js
document.forms.bestformever.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  let formid = e.target.id;
  
  // input "collected" on the submit event
  [...document.forms.dynamicallyaddedinputs.elements]
    .forEach(elm => elm.setAttribute('form', formid));
  
  // input added to the DOM on the submit event
  e.target.innerHTML += `<input name="calculated" type="hidden" value="${2+3}">`;
});
```

```html
<form name="dynamicallyaddedinputs">
  <input type="text" name="userinput">
</form>

<form id="bestformever" name="bestformever" method="post" action="/amaze-me">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="xyz1234">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So could I technically inject required input fields into the `DOM` before submitting the form and this way the form gets field-sized dynamically? This could be an acceptable solution.

Comment: It is up to you to decide when the input elements are added to the DOM. I guess the user also has to write something into the input element before submitting?

Comment: There are input elements which require computation afterwards and then there is additional data computed on the fly. So if that solution works I can still rely on classic form browser support since DOM manipulation is no issue in my case. Thanks for this tip, I will give it a try after some hungry mouths got fed.

Comment: @Slevin a more dynamic example is added to my answer.

Comment: Well, that's a really viable solution I can work with. Many thanks for this piece of code. Exactly I was hoping for, without `XHR` or some other artificial complicated intervention.

Comment: A last question: Let's assume the calculation takes some amount of time, eg 0.5 seconds. The browser will wait until the end before it sends the form?

Comment: @Slevin as long as the code inside the submit event callback function is procedural (including calling other functions that return something) this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the `submit` function doesn't exactly behave the same as clicking the submit button. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.
> Constraint validation is not triggered.

However, it looks like [`requestSubmit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) does not have such limitations, and will behave exactly the same as clicking submit. Note that this method is run against the Form DOM object, not FormData.

An easier approach is to manually perform the http request and pass in the FormData object. More documentation on this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#associating_a_formdata_object_and_a_form

```js
document.querySelector("#best-form-ever").addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit, false);

async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = document.getElementById("best-form-ever");
  const userInput = document.querySelector("#user-input").innerHTML;

  const payload = new FormData(form);
  payload.append("userInput", userInput);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(form.action, {
      method: form.method,
      body: payload
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="user-input" type="text" name="userInput">

<form id="best-form-ever" method="post" action="/amaze-me">

  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="xyz1234">
  <button id="submit-form" name="submit-form">Submit</button>

</form>
```